# SpringBoot use PUT mapping for create/update resources

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest

Consider following Json body -

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "userName": "test-user1@test.com",    
    "emails": [
        {
            "id": 69,
            "emailAddress": "test-user1-x@test.com"
        },
        {
            "emailAddress": "test-user1-y@test.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

In this example "User" entity has one-to-many relation with "Email" entity. When I update user, I want to update and/or create emails as well. I understand there should be endpoint for creating/updating emails and there should be one for creating/updating user.

> POST /users
>
> PUT /users/{id}
>
> POST /users/{id}/emails
>
> PUT /users/{id}/emails/{emailId}

But I am wondering is it good practise to create/update emails with "PUT /users/{id}" endpoint? Ex: if emails array element has "id" attribute then update existing email. If "id" attribute in emails array is missing then create emails. Is it good way to think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use POST to create only, and PUT for update only.

POST is a method which is changing a state on server means every time you make a post new record is created.

PUT is idempotent, which means for same request result should be the same for any number of calls.

I would recommend this:

> ```
> POST /users
> ```
>
> creates a user
>
> ```
> PUT /users/{id}
> ```
>
> updates user that id is {id}. request body contains user info, id is
>   taken from as path variable from url.
>
> ```
> POST /users/{id}/emails
> ```
>
> creates an email for user id {id}, id is taken from url, email
>   information is in body.
>
> ```
> PUT /users/{id}/emails/{emailId}
> ```
>
> updates an email for user {id} email with id {emailId}, email id is
>   taken from url, email data from body.